# Combine two texture2d to one texture2d using shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Hi，all i can use unity c# code to do combine two texture2d to one texture2d,but it is not efficient，i want to use shader to do it,but i little knowage about the shader.  for example i have texture2d as A,A size is 1024*1024,then i scale it to 100 *100 as B,and put b to the right_up of the A.How to finish it using shader

Answer (score 0):

This's topic may help you but i'm not sure about scale texture, just take a look:
http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/rendering/part-3/